# Ubuntu 11.04 xulrunner: command not found?

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

Now i install Pencil-1.2-0-linux-gtk software in my ubuntu 11.04 system, here i found this problem. **xulrunner: not found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried installing it through synaptic package manager. Just type xulrunner in the search bar and 2.0 should pop up

Comment: I originally suggested an apt-get but I seem to vaguely recall there was some issue with that.

Comment: After that, this error comeError: Platform version '2.0' is not compatible with
minVersion >= 1.9.1
maxVersion <= 1.9.2.*

Comment: THAT was the issue with apt-get i couldn't remember. go back into synaptic and uninstall 2.0 right below it you should see 1.9.2

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally i install the Pencil-1.2-0-linux-gtk